# Importing modules is too slow

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

I've installed the Numpy, Scipy and Pandas modules to my library. Problem is when I import these modules to my code: while running my script, they take way longer to import compared to the python standard library modules. What should I do?

Comment: The numpy and scipy modules are quiet large and are a bit longer to import than most of the modules. It may be normal... what time scales are you talking about.I don't know for panda but I've never experienced what you describe

Comment: Also, tell us a little bit more about what you are trying to do, and a code bit in its current (slow) state. It would also be helpful to know why script startup time is critical to you, in order to figure out alternatives.